# Enable VT-x On My Macbook Pro (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, bios, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am a new flutter dev and my emulator would only work once I enable Vt-x on my Bios settings. Still, I can't find where to enable it. I use a MacBook Pro 10.10.5 Yosemite. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u1MY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several reasons that the emulator is not working. Vt-x should be enabled by default on MacOS AFAIK. I think your problem is, that you don't have HAXM installed.

In Android Studio go to

```
- Preferences
- Appearance & Behavior
- System Settings
- Android SDK
Go to tab SDK Tools
-> Check if Intel X86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) is installed (on the bottom)
```

By default it is not.

Additional info about how to install it can be found on:
https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-macOS

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried this out but it still gives me the error saying: Unable to install Intel HAXM
HAXM device is not found.
Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that HAXM is installed properly. Try disabling 3rd party security software if the problem still occurs.


Do you have an idea how to resolve it?